# 3D secure Checkout Stripe link expired

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I have a Firebase function to create a Stripe Checkout Session:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.secret);
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");


admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://*************.firebasedatabase.app"
});

exports.createCheckoutSession = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, async () => {
        const { priceId } = req.body;
        const userId = req.headers.authorization;

        console.log("User ID:", userId);

        try {
            // Créer le client
            const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
                metadata: {
                    firebaseUID: userId
                }
            });

            console.log("Created customer with metadata:", customer.metadata);

            
            const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
                customer: customer.id, // Passer l'ID du client
                payment_method_types: ['card'],
                line_items: [
                    {
                        price: priceId,
                        quantity: 1,
                    },
                ],
                mode: 'subscription',
                success_url: 'https://ouranos-app.com/redirection',
                cancel_url: 'https://ouranos-app.com/redirection',
               
            });

            res.status(200).send({ sessionId: session.id });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Erreur lors de la création de la session de paiement Stripe", error);
            res.status(500).send('Erreur lors de la création de la session de paiement Stripe');
        }
    });
});
```

Except I think I have a problem with 3D secure, when a checkout session opens, I fill in the card, then do the 3D secure correctly and then the page shows me "link expired".

I think I've put everything I need in my function for 3D secure to work, have I forgotten anything?

Comment: If the "link expired" is showing on a Stripe hosted page, I would suggest you reach out to Stripe Support - https://support.stripe.com/contact with your code, and a link to your test site which replicates the issue so that they can take a look.